# Unable to edit worksheet in an Excel add-in (Office js) after closing a Dialog

Tags: excel, dialog, edit, add-in, office-js

In an Excel add-in, right after closing a dialog created using displayDialogAsync, you cannot edit the cells in the worksheet. If you click anywhere else outside the worksheet (ribbon, task pane, etc), minimize/maximize Excel, or double click a cell, then you can edit again. If you scroll while you cannot edit, everything in excel becomes "un-clickable".
Also, I have noticed that the title bar (where the name of document is shown) remains grayed out until you click outside the worksheet as if Excel didn't have focus.

I was able to reproduce this using the basic Excel Add-in template from Visual Studio:

In the manifest I added a button to the ribbon (to open the dialog):

```
 <Control xsi:type="Button" id="DDR.SettingsButton">
              <Label resid="DDR.SettingsButton.Label" />
              <Supertip>
                <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                <Title resid="DDR.SettingsButton.Title" />
                <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
                <Description resid="DDR.SettingsButton.Text" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
              </Icon>

              <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                <FunctionName>openDialog</FunctionName>
              </Action>

            </Control>
```

Then, a function to the Functions File:

```
function openDialog(event) {
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(window.location.origin + "/functions/Dialog.html", { height: 50, width: 50 }, function dialogCallback(asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status !== "failed") {
           var dialog = asyncResult.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, function (args) {
                dialog.close();
                event.completed();
            });
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, function (arg) {
                switch (arg.error) {
                    case 12006:
                        event.completed();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Then, I created a very simple dialog:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        Office.initialize = function () {
            $('#buttonClose').click(close);

        };

        function close() {
            Office.context.ui.messageParent("close");
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <Button id="buttonClose">Close</Button>
</body>
</html>
```

I experienced a very similar behavior that was being caused  (now fixed) by an iframe that I was embedding in the task panel (original question here: [Unable to edit cells after a setSelectedDataAsync in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729712/unable-to-edit-cells-after-a-setselecteddataasync-in-excel)).

Is there a workaround/fix for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to double check. This is on Windows Desktop (Win32) version of Excel correct? Can you give us the build number you are using? Thank you

Comment: Hi Humberto. Yes, it is the desktop version. Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.7726.1026) 64-bit

Comment: Hi, any news on this? I didn't experience the behavior for a couple of days, then it started to happen again yesterday. Seems weird to me that is not consistent.

Comment: Hi, we're unable to re-produce this in the recent builds of Excel. Is it possible for you to work with recent Excel version to check if the same issue persists?

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into it. I updated to the latest version of Excel and tested for several days. The issue doesn't happen anymore when I close the dialog using the dialog native close button (top left X button), but still happens (not always) when closing the dialog from a custom button.

Comment: @SudhiRamamurthy Just wanted to add that I have been experiencing this again. Even within Script Lab, if I click the "Reference Docs" ribbon button and then close the dialog, I'm unable to write to the worksheet unless I double click a cell or click anywhere outside of the worksheet.

Comment: This is being looked at right now. Apparently, the problem re-appeared recently after it was fixed. Will get back...

Comment: @SudhiRamamurthy any news on this?