# Clicking inside the task pane content and immediately scrolling over the worksheet causes Excel to become unresponsive

Tags: excel, office-js

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click anything inside the task pane content.
2. Move the mouse over the worksheet (do not click anything).
3. Scroll with the mouse wheel over the worksheet.
4. Notice that Excel becomes unresponsive.
5. Minimize then restore Excel. Notice that Excel becomes responsive again.

I was able to reproduce this with the basic Excel Add-in project template in Visual Studio.

I'm currently using the latest build of Excel (16.0.7726.1030).

Any workarounds?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same exact issue with my task pane add-in that I recently published to the store.  I've tried on multiple PCs:  Issue happens 100% of tries as Mario describes above.  Issue occurs if side-loaded and if added from the store.   I have Excel 16.0.7830.1018 32-bit on all my PCs.  No issues with Excel Online or newest Excel for Mac.  Here's my add-in:  https://store.office.com/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380892.  I believe I've been seeing this issue for weeks, but I've ignored it hoping the Store-installed version would fix it.

Comment: I also tried with the "Script Lab" add-in.  The issue also occurs with it, so perhaps it occurs with all task pane add-ins?

Comment: Whenever user activates another application, then returns to Excel, Excel becomes responsive again.  As a temporary fix, is there some way JavaScript can sense the issue (non-responsiveness) and resolve it?  I would think this issue would be experienced by most users and discourage use.

Comment: All 3 of my PCs are Windows 10 64-bit 15063.138 with the Creators Update.  Could the update cause the issue?

Comment: I now have Excel 16.0.7927.1020 (build 7967.2139) and I am still seeing this behavior.  It also occurs on content add-ins, not just task pane add-ins.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44518443/worksheet-freezes-when-scrolling-on-task-pane-during-task-execution

Comment: @Marc LaFleur - MSFT, with version 1706 (Build 8229.2086), I am still consistently seeing this issue.  Any updates on a fix or some Office.js workaround?  Because my customer's workbooks are long, the first thing they do is scroll down (after activating the add-in) and get locking issue.

Comment: Any news on this issue?

Comment: We're still in the process of fixing this issue. We've identified the overall cause - but the fix or workaround isn't available yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to replicate this using Visual Studio 2017 and Excel 2016 for Windows but only when launched from within Visual Studio. When loaded outside of Visual Studio (i.e. [side-loaded into Excel](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins)) it no longer exhibits this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, Marc. I tested **side-loading** the add-in in 2 different environments:  

1. Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.7726.1030) 64-Bit.  

2. Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.7329.1051) 32-Bit.  

The issue can still be replicated in environment 1, but not in environment 2.
Also, I have been experiencing another issue with the same symptoms in environment 1 ( please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42965277/unable-to-edit-worksheet-in-an-excel-add-in-office-js-after-closing-a-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed. I just try the repro step, it's not repro in my side. please validate, kindly create a new issue or report it via [office-js issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) in github if you still observe unresponsible worksheet.