# Worksheet freezes when scrolling on task pane during task execution

Tags: excel, office365, office-js

We are developping an office Addin with office.js API. 
A recurrent problem damage our reputation in the store.
This problem is that the worksheet in a Excel Addin (office.js) is freezed after scrolling over it.
 I've written a simple Script Lab snippet code which reproduce the worksheet freezing problem. All the steps to reproduce this are described on it. 
The snippet is available at : https://gist.github.com/Nassim33/5eaf0bdb4a5b0b1a8db99f58b6de101e

Comment: In my testing for the last 2 months, it seems to occur with any/all Office for Windows add-ins 100% of tests with all of our PCs.  I am surprised more people have not complained.  I am hesitant to publicize my Store add-in until it is fixed.   I have not found a workaround.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649395/clicking-inside-the-task-pane-content-and-immediately-scrolling-over-the-workshe

Comment: Hello, I'm able to re-produce the issue using your snippet. However not across all builds. Could you please provide your Windows OS version and Office version?

Comment: Hello, thank you for testing. I re-produce the issue using these config:                   
     1) - Excel 2016 16.0.8201.2101 32 bits + Windows 10 version 1607                                                               
     2) - Excel 2016  1705 (Build 8201.2102 Click-to-Run) 64 bits + Windows 10 1703.

Comment: Sudhi, we have tested on all builds over the past few months and it occurs  consistently on all of them on all 5 of our Windows PCs on all Add-Ins (content and task pane).  However, it never occurs on our Macs or Excel Online.

Comment: Sami, can you confirm this is the same issue described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649395/clicking-inside-the-task-pane-content-and-immediately-scrolling-over-the-workshe ?  It only (and always) occurs when scrolling with mouse wheel over worksheet before clicking on worksheet after clicking on add-in?

Comment: Yes I confirm it. It only (and always) occurs when scrolling with mouse wheel over worksheet before clicking on worksheet after clicking on add-in.

Comment: We're still troubleshooting this issue and consistent re-pro has been a problem. We're now looking at larger set of input files where this issue has been seen. will get back with update as soon as possible.

Comment: I have version 1707 and the issue still occurs 100% of tries on all add-ins (content and task pane), all workbooks, and on all 6 of our Windows PCs (but not Macs).  But it only occurs if you scroll (with mouse wheel) over the worksheet before clicking.  If you click on the worksheet first, it will not freeze.

Comment: We're still in the process of fixing this issue. We've identified the overall cause - but the fix or workaround isn't available yet.

Comment: The freeze could be released when switching to another application and back to excel - in our case.

Comment: We are having the same issue!!! 
When will we see a fix from MS? Is this the right channel? @Michael Zlatkovsky - Microsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed. I just verified the gist, it's not repro in my side. please validate, kindly create a new issue or report it via [office-js issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) in github if you still observe unresponsible worksheet.