# office-js window focus

Tags: office-js

Writing an Add-in for Excel 2016 desktop application using the javascript API, I ran into the following problem:

After opening and the dismissing a dialog window using
 Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync
and subsequently
 dialog.close()

The Taskpane takes focus from the main excel window meaning that I cannot move the cursor to a new cell using the arrow keys before using the mouse to give the main window focus again.

**After having spent ages trying to solve this one, I got hold of a Microsoft rep. who told me that it cannot be done.**

Comment: I reported this a few months ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42965277/unable-to-edit-worksheet-in-an-excel-add-in-office-js-after-closing-a-dialog?noredirect=1#comment74886529_42965277 seems like you are experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: @MarioSolís Unfortunately it is not the same, this is not an error - I need to find out how to give the main window focus so I can edit the window without clicking it after the dialog closes. There mus be a way to give the main window focus from an add-in.

Comment: @AntonioNicolaasTeyken any luck with this issue? The web addin is hosted by the Excel process therefore the app in the process cannot promote self to be in focus. The issue sits within the Excel.Run context. That one should be bound to the invoking process specifically.

Comment: @st35ly Unfortunately we decided to make the add-in using native API as we found this to be a blocking issue. I have not looked into it since. Am I reading this right, did you solve it?

Comment: @AntonioNicolaasTeyken I don't thing this is possibke to resolve with office.js lib. What native API have you used if don't mind me asking